# Work done by a magnetostatic field

Tags: energy, work, magnetostatics

How does a (static) magnetic field accelerate objects (like an iron nail) if we are taught that the magnetic force does always zero work?

Comment: Who taught you that?? Electrical motors run on magnetic forces.

Comment: There's a good discussion of this in Chapter 8 of the most recent edition of Griffiths's *Introduction to Electrodynamics*;  but unfortunately I don't have it in front of me to summarize.  I'll try to remember to do so next time I have the book in front of me and some free time.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert The discussion in Griffiths is very good, and it's not wrong; however, it's one of several instances where Griffiths avoids mentioning some additional subtleties.  Magnetic fields acting on current do no work, but magnetic fields also interact with intrinsic spins; it then becomes a matter of precisely how you define "work" when such spins are involved whether the magnetic forces are doing work or not. -Brett